# Is it possible to import just a single configuration parameter, not all in Hydra?

Tags: fb-hydra, omegaconf

constants_config.yaml

```yaml
site:  fb
another_site: google
```

my_config.yaml

```yaml
my_site: ${constants_config.yaml]
```

Resulting my_config.yaml

```yaml
my_site: fb
```

I just want to get a single constant, not the whole constants_config.yaml (which is done by using default)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible directly.
You can do it with interpolation into a constants node.
Something like:

constants.yaml:

```yaml
constants:
  site:  fb
  another_site: google
```

main.yaml:

```yaml
defaults:
  - constants

my_site: ${constants.site}
```

The composed config should look something like:

```yaml
constants:
  site:  fb
  another_site: google

my_site: ${constants.site}
```